# Двойной редирект с http://www.domen.ru на https://domen.ru MODx Evo 1

Tags: .htaccess, modx, redirect, редирект

Правлю редиректы и возникла вот следующая проблема. имеется конфигурационный файл .htaccess, абсолютно дефолтный для modx Evo 1, содержимое

```html
# For full documentation and other suggested options, please see
# http://svn.modxcms.com/docs/display/MODx096/Friendly+URL+Solutions
# including for unexpected logouts in multi-server/cloud environments
# and especially for the first three commented out rules

#php_flag register_globals Off
#AddDefaultCharset utf-8
#php_value date.timezone Europe/Moscow

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# Rewrite domain.com -> www.domain.com -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


#Правило выше выдаёт тройной редирект, правило ниже двойной, без правила ответ 200
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories and images from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

# For Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

# Reduce server overhead by enabling output compression if supported.
#php_flag zlib.output_compression On
#php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5
```

Я понимаю что сперва идет редирект на https, а потом на www, как это можно поместить всё в один редирект? Или он так и останется двойным редиректом?

Comment: А что мешает в правиле с www сразу редиректить на https? А в правиле с https сразу редиректить на www? Чтобы не давать повода для лишних редиректов. Т.е. везде сразу редиректить на `https://www.example.com`